# wordpress plugin activation error

Tags: php, database, wordpress

since moving wordpress site to other server i get this error up on actiovation one of my plugin.

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in ****PATHTOFILE*** on line 656
```

line 656 of error file:

```
$wpdb->update( 'users', array('password' => sha1($_POST['new_password'])), array( 'id' => (int) $this->get_logged_in_user()['id'] ), array( '%s'), array( '%d' ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by `$this->get_logged_in_user()['id']`.

I would suggest checking the value of `$this->get_logged_in_user()`.  You should see an `array` with a key of `id` available.  If not, there is your problem.

It is better practice to not directly access functions that return arrays in this way, you may be better with the following:

```
$logged_in_user = $this->get_logged_in_user();

$wpdb->update( 
    'users', 
    array(
        'password' => sha1($_POST['new_password'])
    ), 
    array( 
        'id' => (int) $logged_in_user['id'] 
    ), 
    array( '%s' ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```